# MYSQL - SUM points from three tables

Tags: mysql, sum, inner-join

I have the following SQL statement (so far):

```
SELECT p.facebookID,p.points,pi.facebookID,pi.points, SUM(pi.points) FROM player AS p 
INNER JOIN invites AS i ON p.id = i.inviteFromID 
INNER JOIN player AS pi ON i.inviteToId  = pi.facebookID
WHERE p.id = 1 GROUP BY pi.points
```

This shall show me, which User where invites by the UserId = 1 and which points they got.

**Goal:**
I need the SUM of all invite-points for chosen UserId.
How can I achieve that? Is my way the right way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't group by pi.points, instead group by user id, i believe... try this

```
SELECT p.facebookID,p.points,pi.facebookID,pi.points, SUM(pi.points) FROM player AS p 
INNER JOIN invites AS i ON p.id = i.inviteFromID 
INNER JOIN player AS pi ON i.inviteToId  = pi.facebookID
WHERE p.id = 1 GROUP BY p.id
```

assuming p.id is your user id

let me know how this works

Comment: It works like a charm. Just had to delete pi.points (don't want the points of the user yet.) Thank you very much!

Comment: Is it somehow possible, to get the count, from HOW MUCH players the points are? That would be my last and final question :)

Comment: hmm - i'm kind of confused on what you mean by "HOW MUCH players the points are" - maybe something like: SELECT count(p.id) FROM player AS p 
INNER JOIN invites AS i ON p.id = i.inviteFromID 
INNER JOIN player AS pi ON i.inviteToId  = pi.facebookID

Comment: thats just a guess, its somewhat hard to say without really testing it locally - know what i mean?

Comment: I mean something like.... there are two invites for the userId 1 with the points 10 and 23 (i.e) - so the inviter would get 33 points from two users. I need to get the users..if you now know what I mean. Hopefully. :)